# Serializing Charts and other controls C#

Tags: c#, serialization, charts, xml-serialization

So i'm trying to serialize my charts, labels, textboxes, and comboboxes, I'm able to do everything except and put it in the same xml file but the charts state, this is what i have in my serializing class.

```
public static void Serialise(Control c, string XmlFileName, List<SampleFileObject> sampleObj) {
  XmlTextWriter xmlSerialisedForm = new XmlTextWriter(XmlFileName, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
  xmlSerialisedForm.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
  xmlSerialisedForm.WriteStartDocument();
  xmlSerialisedForm.WriteStartElement("ChildForm");
  // enumerate all controls on the form, and serialise them as appropriate
  AddChildControls(xmlSerialisedForm, c);
  AddSampleList(xmlSerialisedForm, sampleObj);
  xmlSerialisedForm.WriteEndElement(); // ChildForm
  xmlSerialisedForm.WriteEndDocument();
  xmlSerialisedForm.Flush();
  xmlSerialisedForm.Close();
}

private static void AddChildControls(XmlTextWriter xmlSerialisedForm, Control c) {
  foreach (Control childCtrl in c.Controls) {
    if (!(childCtrl is Label)) {
      // serialise this control
      xmlSerialisedForm.WriteStartElement("Control");
      xmlSerialisedForm.WriteAttributeString("Type", childCtrl.GetType().ToString());
      xmlSerialisedForm.WriteAttributeString("Name", childCtrl.Name);
      if (childCtrl is TextBox) {
        xmlSerialisedForm.WriteElementString("Text", ((TextBox)childCtrl).Text);
      } else if (childCtrl is ComboBox) {
        xmlSerialisedForm.WriteElementString("Text", ((ComboBox)childCtrl).Text);
        xmlSerialisedForm.WriteElementString("SelectedIndex", ((ComboBox)childCtrl).SelectedIndex.ToString());
      } else if (childCtrl is ListBox) {
        // need to account for multiply selected items
        ListBox lst = (ListBox)childCtrl;
        if (lst.SelectedIndex == -1) {
          xmlSerialisedForm.WriteElementString("SelectedIndex", "-1");
        } else {
          for (int i = 0; i < lst.SelectedIndices.Count; i++) {
            xmlSerialisedForm.WriteElementString("SelectedIndex", (lst.SelectedIndices[i].ToString()));
          }
        }
      } else if (childCtrl is CheckBox) {
        xmlSerialisedForm.WriteElementString("Checked", ((CheckBox)childCtrl).Checked.ToString());
      }
      else if (childCtrl is Chart)
      {

        ((Chart)childCtrl).Serializer.Content = SerializationContents.Appearance;
        ((Chart)childCtrl).Serializer.SerializableContent += ",DataPoint.AxisLabel, Series.AxisLabels, Series.Name, ChartArea.Name";
        ((Chart)childCtrl).Serializer.Save(xmlSerialisedForm);
      }
```

I think that's the important part.

Thanks

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You're having a problem because you don't have a Model that's separated from the UI. You Model should be a set of data that is sufficient to represent your UI fully and loading that Model into your UI should recreate the UI state. Then you serialize the Model. What you've done is ugly, hard to maintain and debug, hard to expand.

Comment: Serializing the UI... EPIC. Only winforms developers can come up with such ideas

Comment: I dunno. Isn't that pretty much what XAML is - a serialized UI? Perhaps XAML was designed by a Windows Forms programmer! ;) <--- note

Comment: @MatthewWatson not really. XAML describes UI and Layout, not data. what this guy is doing here is completely disrespecting the fundamental principles of `separation of concerns`.

Comment: I was joking! I even put in `;) <-- note`

Comment: i'm a new to serializing things in c#, sten can you show me an example on how to do what you mention ?

Comment: It's unfortunately a bit too complicated for a simple example. There are also many ways to approach this separation of data, display logic and control logic. See here for an overview on one approach, "Model View Controller": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_view_controller. Start by separating out the data that you want to display from the controls that display it, and write a class to encapsulate that data.

Comment: @UbaldoQuintero Consider all the properties of all UI elements that you're modifying runtime - now create a class structure that can hold these in a LOGICAL manner. That structure would be roughly your model.